What are some of the gods of life a cleric can choose from?
Basically, I have a fairy from the feywild who was noticed by a god of life, due to her desire to help anyone she can, as well as her knack for helping the injured. Problem is, I know like, nothing about the different gods of life, and doubt I could even name one other than like, Gaia or something, but I don't think that fits what I'm looking for. What are some of the life gods that I can choose from?
For context, I'm in a... Scenario, let's call it, which takes place in Hyrule, but I only recently arrived there through a one-way fey crossing, and was born and raised in the feywild, so it would likely not just be goddess hylia, as I just got there. I can't ask the DM for help because there's not exactly a DM for this scenario, and the closest person I have to a DM doesn't know enough about DND to help with choosing a deity.

This is probably more a question for your DM; any answer we could give would by definition be list based.

Wellllll... There isn't... EXACTLY, a DM in this situation... I'm in Hyrule, though, if that helps, @Bagahnoodles

@Tasi This is setting specific, so requires the DM to tell you what gods are available in the setting’s pantheon. But since you’ve specified it’s Hyrule, I assume you’re able to google “gods of hyrule” and see the Hylian pantheon, so I’m unsure what you’re asking for here. Voting to close for needs details.

@ThomasMarkov I'll edit the question, sorry about that

@ThomasMarkov is that better?

Please tell us what this is for. What do you mean you’re in a “scenario”? Are you playing a solo version of D&D 5e? If you’re writing a story, you can do whatever you want, and I don’t think this question is on topic. Please provide the details about the sort of game you’re asking about.

@ThomasMarkov I'm using a DND character for a roleplay thing on reddit, and there is combat. There are rules to follow, and one of which is you can't be too overpowered. I talked to one of the mods on the subreddit about divine intervention, and came to a conclusion, where the mods of the server would play the role of DM when I use divine intervention, to prevent things from getting out of hand, but we need to find a god for my character, and they don't know enough about DND to help with my deity. For all intents and purposes, this is a normal DND cleric, but in Hyrule.

If you're playing a game in Hyrule, there is no official D&D answer to give you. I would suggest going and hitting up the Legend of Zelda Wiki and searching for Hylian deities. And then if there's anyone 'running' the play-by-post, or moderating it, or whatever...check with them to see if one would be appropriate. But, in short, Hyrule doesn't have "Domain-specific" deities because Hyrule isn't a D&D-compliant setting. Your best bet will probably be to hit the wiki, find a deity or 'guardian deity' that looks close enough, and go for it.

Alternately, just hit up the forgotten realms Wiki (or grayhawk, or wherever your character hails from) and search on domains...and just wave your hands and ignore the fact that your deity is now in a different dimension and should have no ability to project power into Hyrule.

Is there something lacking in online sources of either the D&D pantheon or the Hyrule pantheon or for which you perhaps you need clarification? Is this a custom setting that includes Hyrule and one/some/all of the D&D settings?

@Jason_c_o the setting is r/chaoticyigaclan. I'm rping a cleric from the feywild, and neither I nor the mods know enough about DND gods to do this ourselves

Sure, but what do you hope to get here that the various wikis could not provide? It would also be useful to include relevant details of the setting as part of the question. Does the subreddit's setting have its own wiki or similar resource?

I’m voting to close this question because it is a list question, and list questions are off topic.

@ValhallaGH The community guidance on list questions is a bit more nuanced than simply “list questions are off topic”. The stack has lots of good “list” questions. This just isn’t one of them.

This depends on the setting.
The core rules for every modern edition of Dungeons and Dragons tend to be vague about things like cultures, nations, and deities.  This is because Dungeons and Dragons allows for characters from any number of settings.  Whether your character is specifically from Greyhawk, Ebberon, the Forgotten Realms, Dragonlance, or any of the dozens of other settings will be the deciding factor here.  In other words, you'd be as well off asking us for recommendations on which kingdom your fighter could be from.
Now, the Player's Handbook for 5th edition does provide a default of sorts in the form of the Forgotten Realms pantheon, should you decide to choose that.  If so, the available deities of the Life domain are Chauntea, Goddess of Agriculture; Eldath, Goddess of Peace; Helm, God of Protection; Ilmater, God of Endurance; Lathander, God of Birth and Renewal; Lliira, Goddess of Joy; Selune, Goddess of the Moon; and Sune, Goddess of Love and Beauty.  This is an incomplete list, however, as you could reasonably select any non-evil deity.  See this page for a full list.
Though, honestly, you could just come up with something on your own.  The setting is already heavily customized by the sounds of things, and since you've mentioned that nobody running the game actually knows established D&D settings very well, there's no real sense in using a character they don't know.
Besides, there's precident for D&D settings to borrow real-world mythological deities, so choosing something like Gaia or Apollo would be just as valid as anything else.
There is an alternative option.
I would consider the option of simply being a cleric of an ideal.  Rather than picking a specific deity, most editions of D&D allow you instead to worship and/or embody a general ideology or concept.  So, you could be a cleric of mercy, a cleric of honor, or a cleric of justice, for instance.  This would be a setting-agnostic choice.
